# How to know where an automation is used?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

Please I need to know In which Journey Builders, an **Automation** is used in the entire Business Unit.

What is the quickest way to do that?

Comment: Check the name of the *Journey Entry: Audience* step. Should be the name of the Journey.

Comment: a journey entry is for journey, I am talking about automation

Comment: An automation in journey builder can only be used as a journey entry, so as @user3274635 stated, you should check the Journey Entry: Audience step. If this is not what you mean, I would recommend editing your question with more details and clarify exactly what you are asking.

Comment: okay, thank you. Is there a way to know it without opening all the JBs?